# IdentityServer4: "Bearer" was not authenticated

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, bearer-token

I've got a sample solution with IdentityServer4 in one project and an API in a separate project.   I'm using aspnet Identity with entity framework and everything is working fine, but I have one question.

When I run the two projects in my API logs I have this entry (before any calls to API functions are made):

```
2018-04-12 10:54:36.284 +01:00 [Debug] AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was not authenticated.
```

I then make a call  to my API and I get what looks like confirmation everything is working properly:

```
2018-04-12 10:55:01.458 +01:00 [Information] Successfully validated the token.

2018-04-12 10:55:01.470 +01:00 [Information] AuthenticationScheme: "BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt" was successfully authenticated.

2018-04-12 10:55:01.477 +01:00 [Information] AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was successfully authenticated.
```

2018-04-12 10:55:01.577 +01:00 [Information] AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was successfully authenticated.

So just wondering what the first log entry actually means and what I would need to do to fix it?

Comment: What about your identity server config.cs file ?

Comment: @saj added config.cs as requested - thankyou

Comment: in your startup.cs ConfigureServices you have not setup IdentityServer as your JWT Authority see http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/apis.html, also you have IIS set as Windows, why do you need that with JWT or are you trying to mix auth types ?

Comment: Thanks @saj - the  .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(.. is supposed to handle that and I think I've got that bit working now when I make an API call.   The bit I don't understand is from the logs is I get 2018-03-29 15:59:33.355 +01:00 [Debug] AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was not authenticated.    This seems to appear when the site first loads before any calls are made.    My Own API calls now log successes...[Information] AuthenticationScheme: "BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt" was successfully authenticated.

Comment: Update question now to be more specific to the issue